# How to detect the singular value with wavelet analysis

Tags: signal-processing, wavelet-analysis

I have a series data

```
data=Uncompress[
 FromCharacterCode[Flatten[ImageData[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApipY.png"], 
    "Byte"]]]];
```

We can show it

```
ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I put a singular value in position $20$ and $21$.As I know,wavelet analysis can detect it,but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Of course expected more professionnel answer,I just dig in documentation

Firstly,plots wavelet transform coefficients

```
dwd = DiscreteWaveletTransform[data];
WaveletListPlot[dwd]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Select that basis index with minimal energy

```
{basisIndex} = Keys[MinimalBy[dwd["EnergyFraction"], Last]]
```

> `{{0, 1}}`

Ugly to extract that x-value.

```
MaximalBy[
 Cases[basisIndex /. dwd["ListPlot"], a_Line :> a, Infinity][[1,1]], Abs@*Last]
```

> `{{20.1, 1.00915}}`

Answer (score 1):

Simple way not using wavelet

```
Position[data - MedianFilter[data, 3], x_ /; x > 1]
```

> {{20}, {21}}

Comment: Thanks very much,but I have to say,it hard to find that threshold form [those difference value](http://i.stack.imgur.com/thG4N.png)

Comment: If you don't like picking an amplitude for the threshold, then just pick the Position of the largest (absolute) value of data-MedianFilter.